# Get key for login using service principal dynamically python script

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-service-principal, app-secret

I'm running a python script, where o want to use service principal to authenticate.
I don't want to store service principal secret in my script.

Please help me to store the secret key somewhere and access it dynamically in the script using az cli commands.

I need some command which can fetch the secret key runtime and I can pass it to

"az login --servicePrincipal"  command.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I registered an Azure AD application and generated **`client_secret`**:

[image]

To store the above secret key of the, I created an **Azure Key Vault** like below:

*Go to Azure Key Vault -> Your Vault -> Secrets -> Generate/Import -> Create*

[image]

**To fetch the Service Principal secret key via Azure CLI, please try the below commands:**

```bash
az login --only-show-errors
 
$client_secret = az keyvault secret show --name testclientsecret --vault-name testrukkey --query value
$client_secret
```

[image]